# Why are verbs sometimes on the second position and sometimes not?

Tags: verb, word-order

I know that verbs must always be on the second position in sentences but I had recently found some places where this isn't the case.

For example, in one song I find

> Wär’ heut’ mein letzter Tag, ich lebte ihn mit dir.

Surely the lebte would become before the ich, so it can be on the second position.

I have also seen examples like this elsewhere. Can someone please clarify on why this is so?

Comment: The correct term is *position*, not *idea*. I corrected your question with this aim

Answer (score 1):

> Wär' heut mein letzter Tag, ich lebte ihn mit dir.

That's a poetical word order. Standard word order commands:

> Wär' heut mein letzter Tag, lebte ich ihn mit dir.
>
> Ich lebte ihn mit dir, wär' heut mein letzter Tag.

The *Konjunktiv II* used in the above sentence makes it follow the same word order pattern as sentences lead by dependent clauses have:

> Sobald ich mich hinlege, schlafe ich sofort ein.
>
> Ich schlafe sofort ein, sobald ich mich hinlege.

That's because *Konjunktiv II* is a conditional. It works the same as if an *if* was leading the sentence.

Comment: So how is a poetical word order created just by making the second clause a normal standing sentence.

Comment: Main clauses following a dependent clause have the predicate in front, that's the rule. If you don't follow that rule, you employ poetical freedom.

Comment: What do you mean by poetical freedom? What overall difference does it make?

Comment: Your example sentence is ungrammatical. But a songwriter or other poet may choose to disregard grammar in favor of brevity and rhyme.

Comment: Oh ok, so I assume this should not be done and is not done in conversational language.

Comment: Feel free to be a poet when *du bedeutungsschwangeres Süßholz raspelst.*